# Pandas reshaping date frame, groupby bins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I would need your help with reshaping a pandas dataframe. I am fairly new to pandas (already in love though) but this problem keeps blowing my mind.

I work on an environmental study, which involves counting cars on specific routes, taking note of their origin and destination and number of passengers.

The dataframe would look like this (except in reality it contains 10,000s of rows)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date':['20151201','20151202','20151203','20151204','20151204','20151205','20151206','20151207','20151210','20151211','20151212','20151225'],
                   'id':[123,234,543,890,543,123,234,543,123,123,123,890],
                   'event':[1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
                   'city':['AB','YU','CD','CD','YU','YU','BA','AB','CB','BA','CY','CC'],
                   'number of passengers':[1,5,1,20,1,1,5,10,2,25,3,20]
    }
)

   city      date  event   id  number of passengers
0    AB  20151201      1  123                     1
1    YU  20151202      1  234                     5
2    CD  20151203      1  543                     1
3    CD  20151204      1  890                    20
4    YU  20151204     -1  543                     1
5    YU  20151205     -1  123                     1
6    BA  20151206     -1  234                     5
7    AB  20151207     -1  543                    10
8    CB  20151210     -1  123                     2
9    BA  20151211     -1  123                    25
10   CY  20151212     -1  123                     3
11   CC  20151225     -1  890                    20
```

where df['event'] is indicating if city is origin (1) of car or destination (-1) . df['id'] is unique identifier (licence plate) of car.

To make things even more complicated (at least for me), there can be multiple observation of cars going back same route, same day or another day and of course observations are incomplete (car returned for example to origin unnoticed).

```
df.set_index(['id','date','event']).unstack('event').swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)


event          -1    1                   -1                    1
             city city number of passengers number of passengers
id  date                                                        
123 20151201  NaN   AB                  NaN                    1
    20151205   YU  NaN                    1                  NaN
    20151210   CB  NaN                    2                  NaN
    20151211   BA  NaN                   25                  NaN
    20151212   CY  NaN                    3                  NaN
234 20151202  NaN   YU                  NaN                    5
    20151206   BA  NaN                    5                  NaN
543 20151203  NaN   CD                  NaN                    1
    20151204   YU  NaN                    1                  NaN
    20151207   AB  NaN                   10                  NaN
890 20151204  NaN   CD                  NaN                   20
    20151225   CC  NaN                   20                  NaN
```

The goal I have in mind, is to create a dataframe that shows all traffic originating from a city, its destination and the occurrence of observations of  number of passengers (ideally binned into categories such as '(1-2), (3-5), (6-7), (>7) )

Ideally, I would expect the resulting dataframe to look something like this:

```
Origin Destination     0-2     3-5     6-7   >7
AB    YU                1       0      0     0
      CB                1       0      0     0
      BA                0       0      0     1
      CY                0       1      0     0
YU    BA                0       2      0     0
CD    YU                1       2      0     0
      AB                0       0      1     0
      CC                0       0      0     1
```

I have added an origin and destination column via

```
df['origin']= np.where(df['event'] == 1,df['city'],np.NAN)
df['destination']= np.where(df['event'] == -1,df['city'],np.NAN)
```

but the next steps of the reshaping elude me. I have tried a few things with pandas pivot and pandas unstack but it seems that I am missing something as none of it worked. I guess I also would need to use pandas cut at one point for the binning but I failed to reach this stage in my analysis.

Would you be able to point me in the right direction? How would I reshape the data to achieve the view of traffic by origin?

Comment: your output does not match your input. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Apologies and thanks for pointing it out, Colonel Beauvel. I have edited the question to provide a clearer (I hope) example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have my sincerest apologies because this is hard to follow, so if anyone can think of an easier way, go for it, but here you go:

```
df['number of passengers'] = pd.cut(df['number of passengers'], 
                                bins=[0, 2, 5, 7, max(df['number of passengers']) + 1], 
                                right=False)

# Recode the factor levels for readable column labels when unstacked
df.ix[df['event']==1, 'event'] = 'origin'
df.ix[df['event']==-1, 'event'] = 'destination'

# Split the DataFrame, unstack each factor, then join
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    df.groupby('id')['number of passengers'].value_counts()
).unstack(
    'number of passengers'
).fillna(0).join(
    df.set_index('id')[['city', 'date', 'event']].reset_index().set_index(
        ['id', 'date', 'event']
    ).unstack('event').reset_index(level='date', drop=True)
).reset_index()

# Flatten the column multiindex
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel()
new_df.columns = ['id', '[0, 2)', '[2, 5)', '[5, 7)', '> 7', 'destination', 'origin']

# If we don't do this, there will be separate rows for origins and destinations
new_df['origin'] = new_df['origin'].fillna(method='ffill')
new_df = new_df.dropna().set_index(['id', 'origin', 'destination'], drop=True)

new_df = new_df.reset_index()[['origin', 'destination', '[0, 2)', '[2, 5)', '[5, 7)', '> 7']].set_index(['origin', 'destination'])
new_df
```

Gives you this:

```
                    [0, 2)  [2, 5)  [5, 7)  > 7
origin  destination             
AB      YU          2       2       0       1
        CB          2       2       0       1
        BA          2       2       0       1
        CY          2       2       0       1
YU      BA          0       0       2       0
CD      YU          2       0       0       1
        AB          2       0       0       1
        CC          0       0       0       2
```

Comment: thanks Adam for your answer. However when follow up your code, I get an error "Level number of passengers not found" when running line new_df = pd.DataFrame(...). Any idea why? Much appreciated!

Comment: Nope. Still works here just fine. Maybe you're using an old pandas version that doesn't implement one of these methods? I'm using 0.17.0.